# How to get '&' contained query string from url

Tags: c#

I'm trying get query string from url.
i use 'HttpUtility to get query string value.Use 'ParseQueryString', but the content after '&' is imported truncated.

example

```
string url = "https://somewhere.go/hello?name=mac&chess&taste=salty";
string getName = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(url.Query)).Get("name");
Console.WriteLine(getName);
//result: "mac"
```

how to intact '&' contained query string from url.
i tried `UrlPathEncode`, but it's not encode '&' than return same value

Comment: Can you change the source url to encode the name value? So from `mac&chess` to the encoded string `mac%26chess`? The way the URL is build now `chess` is it's own property (without value)

Comment: Your code is not compilable. String doesn't have `Query` property. [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3cu6bd). If you want the result as `mac&cheese`, make sure that the `&` is encoded.

Comment: The given URL contains 3 parameters in its query string: `name=mac`, `chess=` (no value), and `taste=salty`. `&` separates the parameters of the query string in an URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: You can't fix the URL *after* the fact. Whatever generated that should take care to encode `mac&cheese`. Right now, as far as every single browser and language is concerned, the URL has 3 parameters. Empty query parameters are valid, so `chess` is an actual, valid parameter. You may be able to parse the query part using regular expressions or a hand-crafted parser *if* you know in advance what the names are. Otherwise there's no way for your parser to tell the difference between `chess` the name or `chess` as part of another value.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to point out that whatever application is generating those broken URLs is probably susceptible to malicious users injecting/crafting unintended URLs. This could be a security vulnerability (and if URLs are not escaped, likely prepared statements for DB queries aren't used either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is actually three query variables `name, chess,` and `taste` as the `&` delimits the variables.

If you want to encode `mac` and `chess` to be  in the `name` variable you will need to encode the string `mac&chess` with HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mac&chess") then assign it to `name`, which would be encoded to `mac%26chess`. Then you must decode and split on `&`.

Alternatively you can encode your query string like so:
`https://somewhere.go/hello?name=mac&name=chess&taste=salty`
Note that both mac and chess are assigned to name, and when you